# Use SET DATEFORMAT YMD in SQL Server before java jdbc PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement

I need my SQL Server engine to accept dates in YYYY-MM-DD format for a specific insert query that will be executed repeatedly within a loop. This insert query is build using a PreparedStatement.
Therefore, what I need is to run first `SET DATEFORMAT YMD` in the DB session and, in the same session, run `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()` afterwards.
Does anybody know what JDBC methods and in which order I need to run?

Thanks!!

Comment: please post some actual or sample code is possible

Comment: Why don't you set dates as Date objects?

Comment: @agad I cannot do that in the code as it is right now. The easiest way would be to do what I've asked. Do you know how can I achieve that sequence of instructions?

Comment: Um, unless you have your db set to a specific region (or the connection session), a standard `YYYY-MM-DD`-formatted date should be recognized by default - by SQL Server and pretty much all RDBMSs.  You can probably specify the format in your connection string - otherwise, I'd be surprised that not changing the Java code is the more difficult option.

Comment: The region settings are the european ones, that's why I have the problem when dealing with the dates. Changing the Java code, at least in this case, is a lot more time consuming and less efficient (I'm sure about that). Due to your answers I should start thinking on an alternative, shouldn't I?